# Script not running on resume

Tags: 11.04, touchpad, resume

I am running 11.04 on an Asus UL30. I am trying to run a script to fix my synclient settings (which are lost during resume). I have written the following script in /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_touchpad:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#change synclient settings on resume

case "$1" in 

    resume|thaw)

        sleep 15 && synclient TapButton2=2 TapButton3=3 ;;
esac
```

/var/log/pm-suspend shows the following:

> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common suspend suspend: success. Running hook
>   /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_touchpad suspend suspend:
>   /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_unattended-upgrades-hibernate resume suspend:
>   success. Running hook /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_touchpad resume suspend:
>   Failed to connect to X Server.
>
> /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_touchpad resume suspend: success. Running hook
>   /etc/pm/sleep.d/10_grub-common

Not really sure why the synclient changes aren't being chnaged by this script on resume. Would appreciate any insight....

Comment: It's not working because the script runs as root, and also because synclient requires access to your X session. I don't have a solution for you.

Comment: Found an answer.

Answer (score 3):

## Direct answer

In order to achieve your goal (of running an X-session dependent user-space script when your machine resumes) you must:

1. run the script as the appropriate user; and
2. ensure the DISPLAY variable is set.

I would move the line `sleep 15 && synclient TapButton2=2 TapButton3=3` to a separate file say `/usr/local/sbin/setupTouchpad.sh` and replace the line with:

```
   export DISPLAY=:0
   su -c - <yourusername> /usr/local/sbin/setupTouchpad.sh
```

Where `<yourusername>` should be replaced. Note that it is still a good idea to have some sleep time to be sure the system is awake before running the code. Also, be sure to `chmod +x` that `setupTouchpad.sh` script.

---

## A better way

The problem with the above is that you have to hard-code your username (or use some hackish way to discover which user is logged in and has the active X session). It's better to set system-wide touchpad settings for X.

These options may be set in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

For me, the correct file to edit is `50-synaptics.conf` here I've set options, here's a portion of that file:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"

        Option          "TapButton2"              "2"
        Option          "TapButton3"              "3"

        # Etc...
EndSection
```

As you may already be aware, to see valid options simply run `synclient`.

**Note** you must restart X for these changes to take effect. To do so in Ubuntu, for example, you can run `sudo /etc/init.d/lightdm restart`

To preview your changes you may try running the following line (or some variant). Remove  `| bash` from the end to see the commands it's issuing.

```
cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf | grep Option | grep -v "^\#" | awk '{print "synclient " $2 "=" $3}' | sed 's/\"//g' | bash
```

If you Google around for `touchpad settings synaptics xorg.conf.d` you'll find a few good overviews of options, also.

---

**References**

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10663041
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11642979&postcount=622